# lftp - pound (#) sign in sftp password

Tags: ftp, sftp

I was trying to list an sftp directory using lftp:

`lftp -c ' open -u user,passw@#123 sftp-abc.company.com
;
ls -lrt /client_incoming5/file_ran_*.csv '`

I get a `ls: Login failed: 530 Login incorrect.`

But I try the same for another SFTP whose password doesn't have # in it and it works.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you try escaping them `-u 'user,passw@#123'` ?

Answer (score 1):

Special characters have to be escaped with \

Comment: Can you try to separate user and password ?
By using --user and --password options

Comment: Not sure lftp supports that. Tried it and it didnt work.